# How to use Squish tool for Qml

Tags: qt, qml, squish

I need to use squish to test a QML application which loads in Qt-executable.
Coudn't find steps or any example which illustrates the test case recording.

I am able to load the executable which displays qml but it doesn't recored anything.

Went through Squish documentation: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/5.0/

In 'Section 17.4.2', it is briefly mentioned that Squish records in terms of Rectanges and Texts (which is not happening at my end.

It also mentions about a Squish hook in QML objects and moving them in 'extensions' folder. Even that doesn't seem to work.

If you can provide an example of Squish with Qml, it will be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, If you are using Squish under Ubuntu you have to apply a patch to your QT build and that should fix the problem, you can get the patch from here http://download.froglogic.com/snapshots/qt-dynlist-pt2.patch. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the windows/web edition. There is a bug and you should conatct the support and ask for a solution. The have problems to run hybrid edition like win/web.